# Java Swing energybar not updating

Tags: java, swing

Was wondering if any of you could help me with this:

I have a UIMain class with the following methods. My timer doesn't appear to be working whenever I call all 3 in the main method

```
setupEnergyBar();
setupDeductingEnergyBar();
updateData();

public void setupEnergyBar(){
    energyBar = new JProgressBar();
    energyBar.setStringPainted(true);
    energyBar.setMinimum(0);
    energyBar.setMaximum(100);
    setupDeductingEnergyBar();
}

public void setupDeductingEnergyBar(){
    energyDeductTimer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            character.setCharEnergyLvl(character.getCharEnergyLvl() - 5);
    }
    });
    energyDeductTimer.start();
    updateData();

}

public void updateData(){
        character.getCharName();
        character.getCharEnergyLvl();
        energyBar.setValue(character.getCharEnergyLvl());
//          setCharStatus();
//          setCharActionLvl(getCharActionLvl());
//          setCharEnergyLvl(getCharEnergyLvl());
//          setCoins(getCoins());
//          setHero(isHero());
//          setCrimesFought(getCrimesFought());
//          setCrimesCommited(getCrimesCommited());
//          setCrimesIgnored(getCrimesIgnored());
//          
    }
}
```

Many thanks

Comment: you're calling  updateData() outside the timer, so it's only calling once when you call setupDeductingEnergyBar()

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the `setupDeductingEnergyBar` method. You are creating a timer, and updating the characters energy, but you are not updating the progress bar. The fix is just to move the `updateData` method into the `energyDeductTimer`'s action listener.